# How to manage pages/forms on PHP application?

Tags: php, design-patterns

im new in PHP and im trying to write simple online shop.

Lets say have index file like this:

```
<?php  
require_once '/inc/db.php';
$db = new Db();
?>  

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
        <div id="header"><?php require_once("header.php"); ?></div>

        <div id="content">
                <?php
                    // i have no idea what to put here
                ?>
        </div>

        <div id="footer"><?php require_once("footer.php"); ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I created files "add_category.php" and "add_product.php", they contain html forms. They are working, but i want to display that form in content div, and save data in database and i have problem. I want to apply my global header, footer etc. and i don't want to copy my layout from index file to each form of my application.

I have no idea:

- how to display diffrent "pages" in my  (now im trying to manage with switch branching of $_POST['action'] data, but i don't know is this best way)
- where i should "send" data from froms? i mean "action" attribute in . other words - where i should process data keeping constant layout which is "defined" in index.php

I have some books about PHP, but there is no book that says how to build applications. They all are about PHP language and simple tasks on single pages/files.

**I need simple pattern/example/article** about managing forms/pages and communicate between them (by POST for example). Tried to learn from Wordpress sources, but this is a little too complicated to analyze for me (big complicated registry, object caching etc.).

I HAVE NO PROBLEMS WITH PROGRAMMING IN GENERAL (im windows app programmer).

Comment: Wordpress is indeed terrible example to learn from, I myself have hard times when I have to dig into it's guts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of including your scripts into main site template you have to do quite contrary - include your templates into PHP scripts.
You may address your scripts separately or make a single entry point. Both methods doesn't differ too much, but I'd suggest to use former one  for starter.

So, make your site consists of pages, page templates and main template.
Once your script called, it have to process data, and then load site template, which, in turn, will load page template.

An example layout is going to be like this:
a page:

```
<?
//include our settings, connect to database etc.
include dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/cfg/settings.php';
//getting required data
$DATA=dbgetarr("SELECT * FROM links");
$pagetitle = "Links to friend sites";
//etc
//and then call a template:
$tpl = "links.tpl.php";
include "template.php";
?>
```

it outputs **nothing** but only gather required data and calls a template:

`template.php` which is your main site template,

consists of your header and footer:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>My site. <?=$pagetitle?></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
<? include $tpl ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and calls the actual page template:

```
<h2><?=$pagetitle?></h2>
<ul>
<? foreach($DATA as $row): ?>
<li><a href="<?=$row['link']?>" target="_blank"><?=$row['name']?></a></li>
<? endforeach ?>
<ul>
```

For the form it is good idea to make form's action the very same page (so, you can leave form action simply blank).
The request would be sent to the same page, at the top of which you may put a code like this:

```
<?  
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {  

  $err = array();
  //performing all validations and raising corresponding errors
  if (empty($_POST['name']) $err[] = "Username field is required";  
  if (empty($_POST['text']) $err[] = "Comments field is required";  

  if (!$err) {  
    //if no errors - saving data and redirect
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;
  }  else {
    // all field values should be escaped according to HTML standard
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
      $form[$key] = htmlspecialchars($val);
    }
} else {
  $form['name'] = $form['comments'] = '';  
}
$tpl = "form.tpl.php";
include "template.php";
?>
```

it will process your data and either redirect to the same page on success or show the filled form on error

the main idea of this is user-friendly form handling and business logic/display logic separation while keeping most natural site layout - separate files for the different site modules yet common design.

Comment: Glad it helped. Feel free to ask further questions. I have this design tested on the real life projects and hope I learned some pitfalls.

Comment: By very same page you mean index.php? And one more question about last code you pasted. What if i have more forms? I shall put all that validators in my main file? Or put them in file with my form? And where i should put database insert?

Comment: You shouldn't use php short tags, you can have problems with xml code (that starts with <?xml, more ... many hosting doesn't support them. You should check GET/POST values with isset because you'll have notice error if you don't have the post values you expect.

Comment: @Kamil I mean just the same url. It doesn't matter if it's index or not. You are confusing **an address** and a **running script**. Them aren't necessarily be the same. There should be no form validations in the index file at all. An index file can be used only to call handling script. Despite of the url called, each form has to have it's own handler in a separate file.

Comment: @daniele_dll any certain problem you can prove with code? What problem will I have with XML? What's up with isset? Your objections seems no more than superstitions to me.

Comment: @Col. Sharpnel, lol, really? Create a file php that open and close tags and try to output xml and check the result. Said that, it's a bad pratice ignore noticies ... maybe that they seems a "superstition" to you, but the final result is that you hide potential problems in the code.

Comment: @daniele_dll it is no problem to write `echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';` in this PHP file. as for the notices, I never ignore them and I don't understand what are talking about. Can you point out to **certain** problem in my code? Thanks.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel true, you can use echo to avoid this problem, but this is a "workaround" for the problem itself ... just don't use short tags and you will never have this problems. Check the zend certification guide or common framework coding styles, there is a good reason for dropping short tags.

Comment: @daniele_dll thank you for your concern but I see not a slightest reason to abandon very handy feature I am using thousands times throughout all site templates for sake of **one or two** RSS tags  I may happen to create manually. This would be plainly insane, wouldn't it? I am still looking for the feedback on the "notice error I will have" though.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass a GET-parameter `?page=add_product` or `?page=add_category` to your `index.php` and include a matching php-script:

```
<?php  
require_once '/inc/db.php';
$db = new Db();

// if no page-parameter was send, have a default page to display.
define("DEFAULT_PAGE", "my_default_page.php");

if (isset($_GET["page"]))
{
    switch ($_GET["page"])
    {
        case "add_product": $page = "add_product.php"; break;
        case "add_category": $page = "add_category.php"; break;
        // add more cases here
        default : $page = DEFAULT_PAGE;
    }
}
else
    $page = DEFAULT_PAGE;
?>  

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
        <div id="header"><?php require_once("header.php"); ?></div>

        <div id="content">
                <?php
                    require $page;
                ?>
        </div>

        <div id="footer"><?php require_once("footer.php"); ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: MVC-Approach:

```
/index.php
/controllers/home.php               Default page with some welcome stuff.
/controllers/new_product.php        Display form for creating a product.
/controllers/create_product.php     Process POST-data and create a product.
/controllers/new_category.php       Display form for creating a category.
```

index.php:

```
define("DEFAULT_PAGE", dirname(__FILE__)."/controllers/home.php");

// Did the user pass page?
if (isset($_GET["page"])
// Does page contain a valid controller name?
&&  preg_match("~^[a-zA-Z_]+$~D", $_GET["page"])
// Does this controller exist?
&&  file_exists(dirname(__FILE__)."/controllers/".$_GET["page"].".php"))
{
    // Controller exists.
    $page = dirname(__FILE__)."/controllers/".$_GET["page"].".php";
}
else
    $page = DEFAULT_PAGE;
```

Comment: Im using something like this in more simple app. But i don't know where i should send POST request from "add_product.php". When i press the button on form i will go to that page, not index.php...

Comment: If you want to go to `index.php` then write this in your form's `action`-attribute: `<form action="index.php">`. You may change `$_GET` to `$_REQUEST` to match both `$_GET` and `$_POST` parameters and include a hidden input in your form like `<input type="hidden" name="page" value="create_product" />`.

Comment: Im not sure, but building app this way i will have big tree of switches for navigation and form data processing.

Comment: I added some code to play around with. If you want to build some larger web application, I suggest to look for some MVC-frameworks for php. I heart magenta is used often, but I don't have any experience with it. (build my own CMS). Maybe start with a tutorial on how MVC works: http://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php/

Comment: im trying to understand how to organize data flow and how to handle session before i use MVC. Where i should initiate my database connection and handle session, privileges, logon in MVC? @Basti that tutorial is nice (+1).

Comment: You will have some kind of `init.php` that will do DB connection, session&login management and setting up paths etc for every request you get. You can put this at the top of your `index.php`. Your `index.php` then will parse the request (for instance the contents of `$_REQUEST["page"]`) and call the right controller. To actually produce HTML you should use some kind of template engine like Smarty: http://www.smarty.net You may also want to read this Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer Hope that helps! :-)

Comment: @Kamil don't make a too big deal out of this code. It's actually a negligible part, used only to launch your scripts. While you don't need it at all - you can run your scripts separately all right. It makes you write dedicated code to run new_product.php instead of just directly calling it. it just makes no sense. it's just a code to run files. Your web-server can do it better.

Comment: @Shrapnel: There is some thought behind this: Firstly it does not matter whether you call an init-script and then include a controller, or call the controllers directly and have them include the init-scripts. i prefer the first approach. Secondly if you want to have some complex rewriting logic that for instance interacts with your database, you will have to have a php script decide which controller to call. so don't deny sense to this construction too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Start with basics:
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php

First you probably want to post your data to your form, so add action="add_category.php" and method="post" to your form. It's always better to POST to avoid bugs while passing data in the URL (GET).

Then in the PHP part, first check the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] variable. If it says 'POST' it means that the form was submitted.
Check all your vars using isset() to avoid php notices, and do any validation you need to do on those variable. Exemple: $_POST['category'] > 0.

I usually store all my errors in one $errors array and display errors based on the previous validation.

count($errors) == 0 means you have no error, you can then insert / update your database, and you can either show a message to the user stating that the insertion was done, or redirect him using a Location: header to the category list for instance.

Comment: Please add an abstract of the link to your answer in case the link goes dead.

Comment: -1 i have no problems with language, i asked about good pattern, not "how to create function" or "how to create form in html"